# WCF communication between two PCs doesnt work

Tags: wcf

I am trying to make a WCF communication between two machines in which one will act as server and the other will act as client. I am able to make it work within my system , but it doesnt work when i try to connect to my friend's system.

EDIT: A weird thing is happening now. I just started the wcftestclient from command prompt by giving "wcftestclient address". It retrieved the metadata of my friend's server. But, when i invoke the operation, it gives error "no endpoint listening at localhost" . how can it be localhost? it should be my friend's IP address,right?

Comment: we are inside same wifi connection. If i give a wrong ip, my client gives the error... it connects only if i give my friend's correct ip address... but, the operations i invoke dont work on his end. It goes to the service on my system and gives a null value for all attributes which ideally should be equal to values i gave as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<add baseAddress=...>` is a section of the `<services>` section, not the client. To change the base address used by a WCF *client*, you need to set the address on the client section:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://your_friend_ip/address" binding=... contract=..." />
</client>
```

Also notice that you may need to open some port in the firewall of the service to have the request go through.

Another thing, if your friend's service has metadata enabled, then you can add a service reference on your machine (either using VS Add Service Reference, or using svcutil) by *pointing to your friend's service*, and that will create the config with the appropriate endpoint address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We both have turned off the firewall completely. also, i changed the address in client section,as u said. so, can i just delete the service section from app.config? Also, how to check if my friend has metadata enabled?

Comment: If you only want to use the application as a client, then yes, you can delete the <services> section. You can check whether metadata is enabled by trying to browse to the service address - it should show you whether you have metadata enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, i just want my system to act only as client. I deleted the service section completely in my app.config. and , i just have endpoint address in my client section as localhost. And now, i added a service reference to my friend's service. When i run the client, it gives an error that WCF service host cannot find any metadata., this may cause client not to function properly. I guess its bcoz its checking the service in my system and not in his system

Comment: A weird thing is happening now. I just started the wcftestclient from command prompt and i gave wcftestclient address. It retrieved the metadata of my friend's server. But, when i invoke the operation, it gives error "no endpoint listening at localhost" . how can it be localhost? it should be my friend's IP address,right?