# WCF error: No end point listening

Tags: .net, wcf

HI,

I know this is a very common question in case of .Net, but a weird thing is happening. My friend has a wcf service hosted in IIS. I am able to connect to his service by

http://172.16.70.129/newwebsite/eval.svc

Also, when I use wcftestclient to access the service, it is able to get the metadata and download the operations that the service exposes. But, when I try to invoke the operations, I get an error that

"There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/newwebsite/eval.svc/basic that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

He is able to access it in his computer from the wcftestclient, but I am unable to do so. We both are within same wifi connection. And both our firewalls are turned off. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Please tell me you are not trying to access a service on his machine using `localhost`... Also, this appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6155469/759701

Comment: Did you check the innerexception for more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the WCF service is running on your friend's machine.  The `localhost` in the endpoint is trying to reference the service as if it's on your own machine.  To fix this, replace `localhost` with `172.16.70.129` in the endpoint.

Comment: Yes... The default config file in wcftestclient has endpoint address at localhost. That's the problem